# Trying to set up a Django app subdirectory as a subdomain

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, mod-wsgi

I have a Django app set up with Apache and mod_wsgi and it's working fine. I have a Zinnia blog under the same app functioning at the /blog/ subdirectory. So, the blog is www.mysite.com/blog/. What I wanna do is have blog.mysite.com/ point to the /blog/ subdirectory. I'm stumped because I don't know if I should do this through Django or Apache. So, any ideas?

Comment: You should configure your web server firstly (that receives DNS names and makes aliasing). If you use Nginx then configure it. If not you can configure Apache. And of course make sure that blog.mysite.com matches the same IP addr.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be done with Apache config.

I think you have to setup a Reverse Proxy, which will listen to blog.mysite.com domain and proxy requests to www.mysite.com/blog/.

Unfortunately I'm not an Apache pro, so can't help you with configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Completely from memory and can't test it right now, but in the VirtualHost for blog.mysite.com mount it as:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /some/path/wsgi.py/blog
```

In other words, you still mount it with mod_wsgi, but add '/blog' to the end of the target WSGI script path. This should from memory cause Apache and mod_wsgi to remap things so that '/blog' automatically gets added as part of the URL seen by the Django application. Thus it should map to the blog mapped at that location in the URL namespace in the Django urls.py.

Do note that because you are doing it with a distinct WSGIScriptAlias, it will actually load up a second copy of your Django site in memory in a different sub interpreter than the first one. If that is undesirable, you can use WSGIApplicationGroup directive to override which application group they are both running in and set them to be the same. Preferably use mod_wsgi daemon mode if you aren't already and have them run distinct from the Apache child worker processes as well, as that is generally better than using embedded mode.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't seem to work. I got an error:

`Internal Server Error: /blog/favicon.ico`

Don't know if I should change anything in my urls as well...

Comment: The request for /favicon.ico was always going to fail most likely anyway because your Django application likely isn't going to understand such a request. You should use Alias directives to map such special URLs. In other words, that is an unrelated issue. See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide#Mounting_At_Root_Of_Site So do you have any other details of why it failed as that would not be the cause.